# Bayesian networks 'catnet' package cnPlot returning null

Tags: r, igraph, categorical-data, bayesian-networks, bnlearn

I am working with Bayesian Networks for the first time and I am using Catnet package in R. The reason being my data is full of categorical variables and a lot of missing data too. I tried the simple example posted elsewhere in StackOverflow just to get a sense of how it works. While it is able to produce the conditional probabilities of each of the nodes in the network, I am not able to visualize the network graphically for an easier understanding. The `cnPlot(catNetwork)` just returns null. I was wondering if someone with experience using CatNet can point me to the problems with my approach. Thanks.

## Creating a catnetwork:

```
 cnet <- catnet::cnNew(
  nodes = c("sport", "high_hc", "high_hg"),
  cats = list(c("1","2"), c("1","2"), c("1","2")),
  parents = list(NULL, NULL, c(1,2))
)
```

### Setting empirical probabilities

```
cnet2 <- catnet::cnSetProb(cnet, data=ais_v2.sub)
```

### Plotting the network

```
Sys.setenv(R_CATNET_USE_IGRAPH=TRUE)

cnPlot(cnet2)
```

The plot, in the end, returns null. I have also imported igraph library. Not sure what is going on.

For a reproducible example, I tried the same approach as in this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38111183/bayesian-networks-with-the-catnet-package-handling-missing-data):

The code example is below:

```
#rm(list=ls())

### generate random data (not simply independent binomials)
set.seed(123)
n.obs <- 10
a1 <- rbinom(n.obs,1,.3)
a2 <- runif(n.obs)
a3 <- floor(-3*log(.25+3*a2/4))
a3[a3>=2] <- NA
a2 <- floor(2*a2)
my.data <- data.frame(a1,a2,a3 )
### discretize data into proper categories
my.data <- cnDiscretize(my.data,numCategories=2)

my.data

## say we want a2 conditional on a1,a3

## first generate a network with a1,a3 ->a2
cnet <- cnNew(
      nodes = c("a1", "a2", "a3"),
      cats = list(c("1","2"), c("1","2"), c("1","2")),
      parents = list(NULL, c(1,3), NULL)
      )


## set the empirical probabilities from data=my.data
cnet2 <- cnSetProb(cnet,data=my.data)

## to get the conditional probability table
cnProb(cnet2,which='a2')
```

The output of cnProb is:

```
$a2
   a1  a3   1   2
A 1.0 1.0 0.0 1.0
B 1.0 2.0 0.5 0.5
A 2.0 1.0 0.5 0.5
B 2.0 2.0 0.5 0.5
```

But when trying to plot,

```
cnPlot(cnet2)
```

it returns,

```
NULL
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Similarly for me, the example from `?cnPlot` also produces `NULL` and no R plot. Adding a file argument produces no output either. `cnDot(cnet, "cnet")` produces an external `dot` file which can be rendered with `graphviz` but this is not ideal.

If you can get the adjacency matrix or edge list you could pass this to `igraph` or `Rgraphiz` to plot the net manually; `catnet` has the `cnMatParents` function to return the adjacency matrix.

Then just need to define a plot function that takes an adjacency matrix as input. In the function below the plot type can be set to `"i"` fro `igraph` or `"d"` for `graphviz`/`dot` via `Rgraphviz`.

```
plotAdj <- function(adjMAT, type="d", ...){
    
    if(type == "d") {
          g = new("graphAM", adjMat=t(adjMAT), edgemode="directed")
          Rgraphviz::plot(g, ...)
           
    } else if(type == "i"){
          g = igraph::graph_from_adjacency_matrix(t(adjMAT))
          plot(g, ...)
    }
    invisible(g) # return the graph object
}
```

And use like

```
library(catnet)
set.seed(123)
cnet1 <- cnRandomCatnet(numnodes=4, maxParents=2, numCategories=2)
adj <- cnMatParents(cnet1) # extract adjacency matrix

p <- plotAdj(adj, type="i", vertex.color="lightblue")
p # return igraph object

library(Rgraphviz)
p <- plotAdj(adj, type="d", attrs = list(node = list(fillcolor = "lightblue")))
p # return Rgraphviz object
```

`bnlearn` and `gRain` both have nice plotting methods.

---

Page 3 of the  [`catnet reference doc`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/catnet/index.html) shows how to render the `dot` file and open a pdf viewer automatically. On linux, the following opens up a pdf with the plot

```
Sys.setenv(R_DOTVIEWER="/usr/bin/dot") # path to dot on my system
cnPlot(cnet1)
```

Comment: Thanks! This solves my problem. I am using catnet because bnlearn won't learn the structure with missing data and catnet claims to do so. I have anyway put an issue on catnet's github repo to get the creator's attention.

Comment: you're welcome. `bnlearn` has `structural.em` for learning with missing data

Comment: @RforResearch ; I updated the adjacency matrix as the order of the parents / children were in reverse order

Comment: I just realized that and have updated my code too :-) Also @user20650 the problem with my dataset is that >50% of the data is missing because of the nature of the data collection method. Thus, I am looking for a modeling approach that can work with this real-world messy nature of the data

Comment: @RforResearch; yes, missing data is tricky in just one model but even more so in multivariate. I've not used catnet before, but have had reasonable success with structural.em . ps in case you didn't notice there is a catnet function `cnMatParents`, so no need to use  my earlier custom adjacency function.

Comment: Yes, I figured that and works great. I also noticed that cnProb produces very weird results and are a little hard to verify. Maybe that is for a different question.

Comment: I posted that cnProb question here in case you want to answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67272873/interpreting-catnet-packages-cnprob-output-for-a-catnetwork-object